# string from file C

Tags: c, string

I'm reading a string from a file and then, trying to add zeros to the string till it reach 100, and then I'm printing the string, but I don't know what's wrong, I've tried more than one approach , but they all seems not to work.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: server filename \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file==0)
    {
        printf("file couldn't be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    } 
    int i;
    char str1[100];
    //char str2[100];
    //memset(str2,0,sizeof(str2));
     //for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         // fprintf(stdout, "str2[%u]: %u\n",i,str2[i]);

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", str1) != EOF) 
    {
        for(i=13 ; i < 100; i++)
            str1[i]=0;


    }

         for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         fprintf(stdout, "str1[%u]: %u\n",i,str1[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

but I print it I got

```
str1[0]: 119
str1[1]: 111
str1[2]: 114
str1[3]: 108
str1[4]: 100
str1[5]: 0
str1[6]: 0
str1[7]: 0
up till 99
```

I don't understand this although there is a string in the file "hello"
and then I've tried this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: server filename \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file==0)
    {
        printf("file couldn't be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    } 
    int i;
    char str1[12];
    char str2[100];
    memset(str2,0,sizeof(str2));
     //for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         // fprintf(stdout, "str2[%u]: %u\n",i,str2[i]);

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", str1) != EOF) 
    {

     strcpy(str2,str1);

    }

         for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         fprintf(stdout, "str2[%u]: %u\n",i,str2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

and I gave me the exact same result as the first one, so I don't understand what is happening here, and why I'm getting these results. I'll be grateful if you can explain what I'm doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I'm trying to get hello0000000000---till 99 but now it is either printing the zeros and the ascii or printing hello without zeros, is there no way to get them both??

Comment: I think your main confusion is between the number zero and the character zero.  Use '0' (in single quotes) if you want the character zero.

Comment: I tried to use it like this char str1[100] = {'0'}; 
wouldn't the zeros be of type char here, but still they are not being printed??

Comment: If you use `char str[100]={'0'}` you are creating an array, where the first element is the character zero, and the rest of the elements are null.

Comment: so I have to use for loop to get all the elements to be zeros?

Comment: I used this and now I'm getting both to print `int i;
char str1[100];
fgets(str1, 100, file);
for (i=13; i<100; i++)
{
 str1[i]='0';
}

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         fprintf(stdout, "%c\n",str1[i]); `

Answer (score 2):

In the last code snippet, you shouldn't do:

```
memset(str2,0,sizeof(str2));
```

but instead:

```
memset(str2,0,sizeof(char) * 100);
```

Check this link on sizeof: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays#sizeof

Comment: I really don't believe in `sizeof(100)`.

Comment: The size of one hundred is four :)

Comment: If you want to simply print the string (without the trailing zeroes), do `fprintf(stdout, "str2: %s\n", str2);`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of wrong things here.

Most obvious one to me is that you're printing each character as `%u`, which is `unsigned int`. You should print each character as `char`, that is, `%c`.

Second, as pointed out by *fableal*, your `memset()` is also wrong. Using `sizeof(str2)` means size of `str2`, which is a pointer, which, in 32-bit architectures, will be 32 bits. This is obviously not what you want.

Comment: If he wants to display the ASCII code then the code is correct. Small integer parameters passed to the printf-ish functions are integer promoted. Since the OP expects to print the value of '\0', printing as char is not particularly useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it prints "hello" with %c but it now it's not printing the zeros, is there no way to print them both?

Comment: No, there's no way. Anyway, why you want to print a 0? When the string ends, it's a zero :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing the characters is because the printf is printing integers.  Change it to `%c`:

```
fprintf(stdout, "str2[%u]: %c\n",i,str2[i]);
```

Comment: How do you get an upvote while my answer is the same and answered before you? Just curious :)

Comment: Copy-paste: your own worst enemy :)

Comment: @m0skit0:  The votes on this stuff are largely a mystery to me.  One cut-n-paste and you sometimes get 5 votes.  But write a superb answer for another question with funny anecdotes, links to supporting information, and solve cold fusion, and you don't get a single vote.  I'll vote yours up to re-balance some.

Comment: Yeah, so you're just like me then ^^ Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
memset(str2,0,sizeof(str2));
```

is not needed, since this:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", str1) != EOF) 
{
 strcpy(str2,str1);
}
```

overwrites `str2` with `str1` for each iteration. This means the previous string is thrown away. It's possible that you meant `strcat()`, in which case you should have str2[0] = '\0';` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal, if I understand correctly, is to have a character array which will have the single line from a file in it, and 0's besides that. For example:

File:

```
hello
```

Array result:

```
[h][e][l][l][o][0][0][0]...
```

So the easy way to do that is start by init your array to 0's, then read the line out:

```
char str1[100] = {'0'};
fgets(str1, 100, file);
```

To print them you can print it like the string it is:

```
printf("%s\n", str1);
```

But keep in mind you set the whole thing to 0 (null terminators) so you'll only see "hello". If you print with decimals as you were doing:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
  printf("%d ", str1[i]);
```

You'll see hello in ASCII followed by the 0's

```
104 101 108 108 111 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
```